# SSH tunnel between 2 machines using macOS

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ssh

I'd like to create an SSH connection from `localhost` that would go through `host1` and connect to `host2`.

My local machine runs macOS. `host1` and `host2` are AWS machines that require PEM files for authentication.

I run the following command:

`$ ssh -i cert.pem -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1-ip ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N user2@host2-ip`

And receive the following error:

`Permission denied (publickey).`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring for the moment the port forwarding part of your example, you need to use the `ProxyCommand` or `ProxyJump` directives / `-J` option.  From the command line, try this:

```
ssh -i cert.pem -J user@host1-ip user2@host2-ip
```

Since `-J` and `ProxyJump` were added in OpenSSH 7.3 (IIRC), you might need to use the older `ProxyCommand` directive in your `~/.ssh/config` file, especially if your `ssh` on your Mac is not updated recently.   Also, this allows you to specify other options such as `IdentityFile` to put your PEM file, as in:

```
Host host1
    User host1user
    Hostname host1-ip
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert.pem

Host host2
    User host2user
    Hostname host2-ip
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert.pem
    # hop through host1
    ProxyJump host1
    # or if older ssh-en, one of: 
    #ProxyCommand ssh -A host1 nc %h %p
    #ProxyCommand ssh -A host1 -W %h:%p
```

With that in place, it shoud be as simple as:

```
 ssh host2
```

To add your port forwarding:

```
ssh host2 -L 9999:localhost:1234
```